# form_build_id blind sql injection

Tags: 7

I'm not a drupal developer and have very little experience using it, but I've been given a report for a site which says that on a page containing a form the form_build_id is a blind sql injection threat.

From what I've researched the form_build_id is used to cache a particular build of the form.

Does that mean form_build_id value is stored in the DB?

Here is the true payload as an example

```
form_build_id=form-U_SzHrwRwu2gzwSHtjxrteopmMjv7DHL9Kct1PePW1s%20or%204%3D4%20-- %20
```

False payload

```
form_build_id=form-U_SzHrwRwu2gzwSHtjxrteopmMjv7DHL9Kct1PePW1s%20and%204%3D3%20-- %20
```

the site is running on drupal 7.37 and has this patch applied https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005 (by checking line 739 of database.inc)

Thoughts on solving this or maybe it's a false positive?

Comment: The build ID is used as part of the cache ID for the form, so it'll be used in the key in whatever cache store you're using for `cache_form` (usually database, yes). All DB-related cache queries use prepared statements, so there shouldn't be an issue. If the "true payload" you have represents what's already in your build IDs when the form is built and rendered, then you have a problem; audit your site to make sure there's no malicious code, as the core form API would never generate a build ID that contains an SQL injection attempt

Comment: Hi @Clive, when I load the form myself i get a standard build id by the look of it `form-1NFXbVhCpQnd7h0ZdrdOtSclYxAV9_k4Laa9MhjcT1c"` . I couldn't submit a form using the build_id containing an injection attempt either.

the security report also has this cookie as part of the request to generate the response `s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_fid=27DF0B581B0B4834-21CE239D4AD07122; s_cc=true; has_js=1; SESSa50b56c349c99523bc93d490cf9844c3=6XMnkDoCliV6GRyUdY6YJKC 8P1qwAxXT1tR9xB3YRAI;`

Thanks for the info